# 'Host key verification failed' error message because host key changed in an SSH connection that was previously all right

Tags: ssh, remote-server, ssh-keygen

I used to connect to a server via SSH. But after about a year of not connecting to the server, I tried connecting again when I was met with the error message 'Host key verification failed'. How do I rectify this in order to connect with the server again?

I searched for this in the net and wanted to delete the line manually but could locate the key. the 'ssh-keygen -R' command didn't seem to work also

Comment: Most likely, you just need to remove the server's entry from `.ssh/known_hosts`, and accept whatever key is presented the next time you try to connect.

Comment: While @chepner is correct, note that the message is to help protect you against a "man in the middle" attack. It is warning you that you may not actually be connecting to the server you believe you are connecting to. Unfortunately, [Many people will automatically accept changed keys, and thus enable the attacker to do anything to their connection](https://www.ssh.com/academy/attack/man-in-the-middle)

Comment: Okay thank you, I am able to connect to the server again. I am sure that the server changed the host key, so it is not a security concern.